# Hashing a byte array

Tags: c#

I have an input byte array which is huge in size ( > 8000 bytes). I need to store this byte array in DB, and fetch later for further operation.

The problem is, this byte array column is unique. Assume that if I need to retrieve the entire table information on this byte array column. It becomes extremely costly operation when it comes to byte comparison. So thought of storing the Hash Value of this byte array just to make the comparison operation easier.

Just wanted to know if hash value which is generated from the byte array will be unique OR is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: A hash is by definition not unique for all inputs. What _exactly_ is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size (in bytes) of the hash is smaller than 8000, this is not possible. After all, there are 256 ^ 8000 possible inputs, so there must be at least that many possible outputs if the hash function needs to be unique.

As the default C# hashcode returns an `int`, which (depending on your architecture) is 32 or 64 bits (so 4 or 8 bytes), this is not even close to be possible with the default hash function. (Of course, you could write your own hash function, but that's quite pointless.)